# Flip an image without the "flip" function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've been trying to make a program to flip an image in MATLAB without the function flip, only the horizontally flip works. I don't know how to fix it. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
function flip(a,flag)
a = imread('woman.bmp');
  [x,y]= size(a);
  flag=input('1 to flip vertically, 0 to flip hortizontallly:')
  if flag == 1
    for i=1:x
      for j=1:y
          v(i,j) = a(i,y-j+1);
        end
    end
   end
imshow(v);title('Image flipped horizontally')
  if flag == 0
    for i=1:x
      for j=1:y
        h(i,j) = a(x-i+1,j);
      end
    end
   end
imshow(h(i,j));title('Image flipped vertically')
```

Comment: If you're using `input` to get the flag, then why do you have `flag` as an argument of the function? Also, I'm not sure if this is your main issue, but the `imshow` statements should be **inside** of the if blocks.

Comment: Is this homework? Why can't you use flip( ) or flipud( ) or fliplr( )?

Comment: You don't need loops for that; you can use indexing along the intended dimension. See [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and [`end`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html)